# Checking for matching elements in two lists... One method re-orders the list, the other does not. What's the difference here?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am coming up with a method for excluding punctuation, or any characters not in a list 'chars', from a string. What is the difference between the two methods shown here for creating the set of characters from the string that are contained in 'chars'? Why is one re-ordered and one isnt'?

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = string.ascii_letters
>>> chars = list(letters)
>>> chars
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

>>> subject = "H&e(l0l-o $W)o%r%l*d"

>>> [item for item in subject if any(x in item for x in chars)]
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

>>> [i for e in chars for i in subject if e in i]
['d', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'H', 'W', ' ']
```

edit****

```
>>> [item for item in subject if item in chars]
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version you iterate over `subject`, looking for instances of `chars`. As a result, the output is ordered the same way `subject` is.

In the second version you iterate over `chars`, looking for each instance in `subject`. This means the output is ordered by the characters in `chars` (you'll notice that it's in lexicographical order).

If you expand the list comprehensions you'll see why that happens

**First Version**

```
for item in subject:
  if item in chars:
    print item
```

**Second Version**

```
for e in chars:
  for i in subject:
    if e in i: # This should really be e == i
      print i
```

Comment: thanks, that's easier to understand than I thought it might be.